# What is the use of SinglyLinkedList method in this class?

Tags: class, this, singly-linked-list

What is the use of SinglyLinkedList method in this class?

```
 class SinglyLinkedList {
 public:
 int data;
 SinglyLinkedList *next;
 
 SinglyLinkedList (int data){
 this->data=data;
 this->next=nullptr;
 }};
```

Comment: Are you asking what a constructor does?

Comment: No, why we need the constructor in the above code?

Comment: Same as in any other code - to initialize the newly created instance of the class.

Comment: The constructor needs to have the exact same name as the class (including punctuation).  The reason there is a constructor is: when you create an object of a class without a constructor, the values of its members are just random values.  But what you really want is something predictable so you either need to set predictable vales when you create the object (`SinglyLinkedList s{data,NULL};`) or you need to have a constructor that does that for you so that you don't have to remember to do it every time.

Comment: Because if you don't initialize the `next` pointer to `nullptr`, iterating over the nodes will invoke *Undefined Behavior* as it does not know where the end of the list is. (like the *nul-terminating* character in a C-string)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a C++11 question (not even C++) per se. So ideally it shouldn't have been posted here in the first place.

Secondly, `singlylinkedlist`  is not a constructor. Class name is `SinglyLinkedList`, whereas function name is `singlylinkedlist`.

Assuming that this is a typo and that the intention is to have a constructor over here, the objective of this constructor is to initialize the node in linked list.

There are umpteen number of resources out on the web that explain the linkedlist construction in C++, in future, please refer to them & do your homework before posting the questions here. This helps the community to focus on genuine  **C++11** questions.

Answer (score -1):

You've got wrong information. SinglyLinkedList is use to hold the actual nodes. It serves as the container. Your code above is the actual Node class, not singly linked list

```
//this is the actual nodes that will be stored in linked list which is an another class
class Node{
   public:
       int data;
       Node *next; //pointer to the next Node

       Node(int value){
           data = value;
           next = nullptr;
       }
};

//linked list class
class singly_LinkList{
    public:
        Node* head;
        Node* tail;
        //the head will hold the very first Node object
        //the tail will hold the very very Node object
};
```

Comment: You don't need two classes. Any subsequence of a singly linked list is a valid list